# Javascript filter parent array by value in child array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a 3-layer array that I want to filter out data based on the child array values. I can get semi-correct results but the last part I am having issues with.

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "grandparent": "Timmy",
    "parents": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "parent": "Johnny",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "child": "Sam",
                    "checked": true
                },
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "child": "Ted",
                    "checked": false
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "parent": "Jessica",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "child": "Sam",
                    "checked": false
                }
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

**I have this so far:**

```
    grandparents.value = value.value.map((el) => ({
        ...el,
        parents: el.components.filter((parent) => parent.children?.some((child) => child.checked))
    }))
```

**and it returns this result:**

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "grandparent": "Timmy",
    "parents": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "parent": "Johnny",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "child": "Sam",
                    "checked": true
                },
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "child": "Ted",
                    "checked": false
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

So the parents array is working. However, I also need the children array to also filter out if they are not checked.

**Expected results**

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "grandparent": "Timmy",
    "parents": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "parent": "Johnny",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "child": "Sam",
                    "checked": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Is `el.components` supposed to be `el.parents`?

Answer (score 0):

`filter()` will only add or remove the object, not alter the inner `children` array.

---

You could adopt a [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) option where you

1. for each parent, `filter` the children
2. `if` we got a child, add this object with the updated `children` array
3. otherwise, don't add this parent

```js
let data = {"id": 1, "grandparent": "Timmy", "parents": [{"id": 1, "parent": "Johnny", "children": [{"id": 1, "child": "Sam", "checked": true }, {"id": 1, "child": "Ted", "checked": false } ] }, {"id": 2, "parent": "Jessica", "children": [{"id": 1, "child": "Sam", "checked": false } ] } ] };

data.parents = data.parents.reduce((p, c) => {
  const children = c.children.filter(c => c.checked);
  if (children.length) {
      return [ ...p, { ...c, children } ];
  }
  return p;
}, []);

console.log(data);
```

---

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "grandparent": "Timmy",
  "parents": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "parent": "Johnny",
      "children": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "child": "Sam",
          "checked": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`map` over the `parents` array, for each parent, we filter the `children` array to keep only the checked ones, after that use `filter()` again to remove parents whose children array is empty after filtering.

```js
const data = {
    "id": 1,
    "grandparent": "Timmy",
    "parents": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "parent": "Johnny",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "child": "Sam",
                    "checked": true
                },
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "child": "Ted",
                    "checked": false
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "parent": "Jessica",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "child": "Sam",
                    "checked": false
                }
            ]
        },
    ]
}

const filteredData = {
  id: data.id,
  grandparent: data.grandparent,
  parents: data.parents.map((parent) => ({
    id: parent.id,
    parent: parent.parent,
    children: parent.children.filter((child) => child.checked)
  })).filter((parent) => parent.children.length > 0)
};

console.log(filteredData)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to apply filtering not only to the parents array but also to the children array within each parent.

current code will filter out parents whose children are not checked, and it will also filter out unchecked children within each parent

```js
const data = {
    "id": 1,
    "grandparent": "Timmy",
    "parents": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "parent": "Johnny",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "child": "Sam",
                    "checked": true
                },
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "child": "Ted",
                    "checked": false
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "parent": "Jessica",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "child": "Sam",
                    "checked": false
                }
            ]
        },
    ]
};

const result = {
    parents: data.parents.filter(parent => {
        parent.children = parent.children.filter(child => child.checked);
        return parent.children.length > 0;
    })
};

console.log(result);
```